# Provide infinite sequence of coprime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Provide an infinite sequence of natural numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ such that  I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with that. any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is certainly correct: if you choose $x_n$ to be $p_n^2$ (the square of the $n$th prime number), then

- none of the numbers $x_n$ are prime numbers $\checkmark$, and
- any two $x_n$ and $x_m$ are coprime to each other $\checkmark$

The latter part is true because

- $\gcd(p,q)=1$ for any distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$
- $\gcd(ab,c)=\gcd(a,c)$ if $\gcd(b,c)=1$, for any integers $a,b,c$

and therefore $$\gcd(x_n,x_m)=\gcd(p_n^2,p_m^2)=\gcd(p_n,p_m^2)=\gcd(p_m^2,p_n)=\gcd(p_m,p_n)=1$$ for any two prime numbers $p_n$, $p_m$.

Comment: ahh thanks ! how would you write it so theres an infinite sequence of natural numbers ?

Comment: @rprogramr: Not sure what you're looking for; I would say that the sentence
$$\text{“Define $x_n$ to be $p_n^2$, the square of the $n$th prime number”}$$
gives an infinite sequence of natural numbers, since there are infinitely many prime numbers.

Comment: alright I see thank you for the feedback ! :)